# use a struct into an other struct c

Tags: c, struct

I have a problem using a `struct` in the **C** language.

It is very strange !!! 

I cant use `course` struct in `student` struct. 
I have defined it before but ... 
why?

```
struct course
{
    int no;
    char name[30];
    int credits;
    float score;
};

struct student   
{
int no;
char name[50];
course c[3];
};
```

My language is **c** not **c++**

Comment: "My language is c not c++" I bet if it were C++ you wouldn't be asking this question :-)

Answer (score 8):

One of the differences between C++ and C is that you can omit type keywords such as `class` and `struct` when using C++ types.

The problem is the line `course c[3];`. In order to make it work, you have two choices--you can use a typedef on your `struct course`:

```
typedef struct _course  // added an _ here; or we could omit _course entirely.
{
    int no;
    char name[30];
    int credits;
    float score;
} course;
```

or you can add the keyword `struct` in front of the broken line, i.e. **`struct`**`course c[3];`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to prefix the struct name with the `struct` keyword:

```
struct course
{
    int no;
    char name[30];
    int credits;
    float score;
};

struct student   
{
    int no;
    char name[50];
    struct course c[3];
};
```

Answer (score 3):

```
struct course c[3];
```

should work...

Answer (score 2):

```
struct student {
    /* ... */
    struct course c[3];
}
```

or

```
typedef struct _course {
    /* ... */
} course;

struct student {
    /* ... */
    course c[3];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should actually be able to define an anonymous struct and then typedef it, so:

```
typedef struct {
    /* stuff */
} course;
```

and then as the others have said,

```
struct student {
    course c[3];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

typedefs are helpful, because they allow you to shorten declarations, so you are not always having to type the word `struct`.

Here is an example involving typedef-ing your structs. It also includes a course struct in the student struct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct course_s
{
    int no;
    char name[30];
    int credits;
    float score;
} course;

typedef struct student_s   
{
int no;
char name[50];
course c[3];
} student;

bool isNonZero(const int x);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int rc = 0;

    student my_student;
    my_student.c[0].no = 1;

    return rc;
}
```